# pop-up com barra de progresso python

Tags: python, windows, progress-bar

Atualmente estou migrando um sistema para python e ele tem uma janela que abre fazendo a barra de progresso.
Nesta minha migração utilizei o `tqdm` para gerar uma barra de progresso no sistema, porém em outra parte do código usei o ctypes como no exemplo abaixo:

```
verify = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, 4)
```

Gostaria de saber se consigo usar o ctypes também para chamar a barra de progresso (ou algo parecido) do Windows no python, já que já o utilizo em outros fins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poder pode. Não tenho um windows aqui pra colocar alguns exemplos - mas o mais provável é que você possa chamar essas funções já prontas pra uso no Python na pywin32 - https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32 - vai ser bem melhor do que chamar usando ctypes por que ao chamar uma função em código nativo a partir do Python usando ctypes, você tem que se preocupar com problemas de conversão de tipos, alocação de memória, e erros nessa parte podem fazer o interpretador parar de repente, sem um erro com stack trace, que descreve exatamente o que deu errado.

Então se existe uma biblioteca pronta que já acessa as mesmas funções, sempre é preferível usa-la, já que ela vai fazer toda essa parte - e aí o seu código só tem que lidar com coisas em Python puro, e fica bem mais simples.